# Automatically fill out textarea field from my database when selecting dropdown menu item

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

How can I automatically fill a textarea field with the text from the database and automatically display the associated text when selecting an item from the dropdown menu.

Textarea field were I want to post the data in:

```
 <textarea 
        class="dropDown" Name="dropdownItem" Type="Text" id="dropdownItem" placeholder="New Option"
 ></textarea>
```

Thats only a quick try that prints out the same input as the dropdownItem from my database.

```
<script>

    var select = document.getElementById('select');
    var input = document.getElementById('TextAreaTemplate');  
    select.onchange = function(){
        input.value = select.value;
    }

</script>
```

I already connect to the database, but I just don't know how to do this. 
Do I need more JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing here is only putting the value from your input to your textarea.
You need to make a query to your database with the value you get from your input.
I guess your connection is made via PHP (since you put the PHP tag), so I would recommend you to use AJAX request to create your query with the value from your input.

Then, your response should contain the associated text to display in the textarea.
I found [this resource](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp) which show the basis of AJAX and PHP if you need, but you probably can find better.